# (Archive) Swift Range support floating point numbers?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

It seems that Swift allows, in Xcode Beta, floating point number in the range operator however the results are not desirable.

```
for i in 0..109.88 {
     i
    sin(Double(i))
}
```

This causes it to hang or run for a very long time. Perhaps this is just an oversight in this release and it should only allow integers? Does it even make sense for it to allow floats?

(UPDATE: this is the very old behavior of Swift 1.0 Beta probably could be archived).

Comment: It looks like Apple's implementation of this for loop does `for var i = 0; i != 109.88; i++` instead of `for var i = 0; i < 109.88; i++`. This makes the loop run forever. At least that's my guess. Submit a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: Yep, I agree. I filed a bug report.

Comment: I would like to point out that Ranges with floating points do make sense elsewhere such as **pattern matching**: `switch floatValue { case 0.5...1.5: ... `

Comment: Oh int4resting. So maybe they just need to fix their loop end so it is a less than.

Comment: Personally I'm unhappy regarding most of you-can-only-find-it-in-swift language design decisions. Like having a `for` loop that can't work with floats, absence of generators or even `++` operator. I literally dislike everything I see or write in the language. And for a long time I was feeling like I must be wrong, there should be a reason, a higher purpose for doing things this or that way. But I find the only explanation to this, the language is sort of a vendor lock for developers, once you use it there's no road back. And from what I see in this question it's a pretty badly prepared one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks guaranteed to hang.  Running this:

```
for i in 0..1.5 {
    println(i)
}
```

Shows that `i` is incremented by 1.0 each iteration to infinity. It might be waiting for `i == {upper limit}` to break the loop, which never happens.

Answer (score 1):

In the released version, this is resolved.

Joseph A Mark's answer indicated that a real number is used to increment the values. on testing the range 1.1...5.1, Swift indicated that the real range didn't have an automatic generator, so it couldn't be done.